# Error 500 when uploading Laravel project to server

Tags: php, linux, laravel

When I upload my Laravel Blog and try to view it I get a 500 error (Internal server error).

I'm very new to laravel so I don't have much experience yet. But I've already tried some things. I've read that the root directory from Laravel needs to be in the /public folder. But when I go to {domain}/public it doesn't solve the problem.

Of course I changed the Database configuration from local to the configuration of the server.

Is it possible that the server I use doesn't support Laravel since it isn't the default PHP? Or does somebody know an easier fix?

I know that Error 500 can be caused by different problems. But on localhost it works fine.

This is the error log I get:

```
[2016-09-09 22:41:38] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider' not found' in /home/nieckki171/domains/nieckki171.171.axc.nl/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:146
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  
[2016-09-09 22:41:39] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider' not found' in /home/nieckki171/domains/nieckki171.171.axc.nl/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:146
Stack trace:
#0 {main}  
[2016-09-09 22:41:47] local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class 'Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider' not found' in /home/nieckki171/domains/nieckki171.171.axc.nl/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php:146
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Whenever you get HTTP 500 your first step should be to look at your logs. They probably contain more detailed information that will be necessary to troubleshoot this effectively.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the fast answer! I will take a look at it. When I (can't) find the solution I will share it here.

Comment: I guess this link may help you
https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.ek58ccqm7

Comment: Do your files have the right permission? What do your `storage/log/laravel.log` file says?

Comment: I've switched from host and now I get an error log: The log says that classes are missing: http://pastebin.com/ikXgrdCQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have `composer` in your server.If not, please use

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php — –filename=composer
```

Then

```
$ php composer install
$ php composer dumpautoload -o
$ php artisan config:cache
$ php artisan route:cache
```

For more details, use [this](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e#.phv8n0czd) site, which was suggested by @mfadel

Comment: I don't have access to the command line of the server. I guess that is going to be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you run a composer install on the server.